# How to make an autoclicker in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple autoclicker, I want it so that if i press a command key, ('a' for example), it will hold down the down arrow for 10 seconds, then the up arrow for 10 seconds. Repeat cycle until 'a' is clicked again. This command should be universal to the rest of the desktop as well.

```
import time

running = True

if running == True:
    print("a"), time.sleep(3), print("b")
```

instead of print a/b i want it to press the up key on my keybaord and down key, and running = True should ben changed to a key command.

Comment: You could try using https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Answer (score 0):

**Keyboard Packages**

You can use this package to do actions on a `keyboard keypress`.

Before using you should install it:

```sh
python3 -m pip install keyboard
```

And then here's how to use it:

```
import keyboard as kb
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
        print("Space pressed.")
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for contributing to StackOverflow.
If you don't understand a user's question, please ask for clarification in the comments on their question rather than posting an answer - it's much better to have a clear question with clear answers, rather than answers that don't quite help the OP.
Thanks so much!